# Embed React router link inside a string

Tags: arrays, string, arraylist, react-router, jsx

Why does this return [object.OBJECT] instead of the linked URL?

```
const floors = [
  {
    name: <Link to='/floor/ll-floor'>Lower Level</Link>,
    callNumbers: 'A, C, G-GV, H-HX, J-K-L, Q-TX (except TR), U-Z',
    servicePoints:
      'Reserves, Microtext, Engineering Library Collection, and Media Desk',
  },
  {
    name: <Link to='/floor/1st-floor'>First Floor</Link>,
    callNumbers: ' ',
    servicePoints:
      'Circulation, ' + (<Link to='/ask-us-desk' > Ask Us Desk</Link>) + ' University Archives and Rare Books & Special Collections Reading Room',
  },
```

This is an object that I'm using as data file to populate a table. I'd like to link a few of the items in the data file to different destinations  within the string. "servicePoints" is used to populate data within a column for this table.

Comment: You are seeing [object.OBJECT] in UI or in console?

Comment: I'm seeing it in the UI

Comment: You'll want to include more of the surrounding code. Need to understand if it's embedded in other JSX or vanilla JS. Try to include a complete JSX expression.

Comment: Because a Link is a react component, not a string. You're trying to concatenate a string with a component which is typeof object. Try wrapping it with `{}` instead of `()` to have it treated as an expression instead.

Comment: Will: I've included more of the code to give you a better idea of the context. 
Brian: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that but it breaks the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way by simply making the cell data into an array rather than trying to concatenate a string:

```
callNumbers: ' ',
servicePoints: [<Link to='/ask-us-desk'>Ask Us Desk</Link>, ', Circulation, University Archives and Rare Books & Special Collections Reading Room'],
```